# Generate points(x,y) on rectangle uniformly

Tags: c++, math, random, uniform

I would like to generate points(x,y) uniformly on rectangle. First You input minX and maxX and minY maxY and then you generate the (x,y) uniformly, The basic code is shown below is any better way to achive it? (I need it to monte carlo method to make a plot)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
double drand(const double min = 0., const double max = 1.)
{
    return (max - min) * static_cast<double>(rand()) / static_cast<double>      (RAND_MAX)+min;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(unsigned short int i=0;i<1000;++i)
    {
        std::cout << "x " << drand(minX, maxX) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y " << drand(0., maxY) << std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Better" in which sense?

Comment: For starters setting a seed might make sense, but I otherwise agree with blackbird.

Comment: Don't you need two loops?  One over x, and an inner loop over y.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `rand()`. Your barrier isn't all that high since almost *anything* is better than `rand()`. Since you apparently have C++11, why don't you use the much superior random number generators offered by C++11? For example,

```
#include <random>

double drand(const double min = 0., const double max = 1.)
{
   static std:: mt19937_64 mt_generator(std::random_device());
   static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> u_0_1(0.0, 1.0);

   return min + (max - min) * u_0_1(mt_generator);
}
```

Comment: I have a noob question: why did you use the static keyword? I tried it and found out that with static it's faster (if we call the this function many times), so I was wondering why. Also, why didn't you use min and max directly in the initialization of std::uniform_real_distribution<double> ? Would then the static keyword help as well?

Comment: @orbit You have to be very careful in constructing a timing test. You almost certainly have done something that yields an erroneous result. Creating a Mersenne Twister generator is computationally expensive,  as is creating a `std::random_device()`. It's very, very easy to make a mistake in constructing a timing test; I've made that mistake myself. Regarding the use of `static` for the generator:   There is no reason to do that but once. That said, I could have made the distribution automatic rather than static. Constructing a `std::uniform_real_distribution` isn't all that expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misread your question, I would expect to see something like this Java code:

```
int nx = 10;
int ny = 10;
double x = xmin;
double dx = (xmax-xmin)/nx;
double dy = (ymax-ymin)/ny;
int id = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
    double y = ymin;
    for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {
        System.out.println(id, x, y);
        id++;
        y += dy;
    }
    x += dx;
}
```

I print these values, but you probably want to store them in a data structure that you can feed to your Monte Carlo simulation for evaluation.

Comment: There's a distinction between _randomly_ distributing points (as OP does (but didn't quite say that's what he wanted)), and _uniformly_ distributing points (as you do).  If there's no qualification, "random points uniformly distributed" would probably mean that he wants his points independent and identically distributed, which his original code accomplished.

Comment: Here's what I read: "I would like to generate points(x,y) *uniformly* on rectangle. First You input minX and maxX and minY maxY and then you generate the (x,y) *uniformly*"  I see no random here.  The randomization comes when he evaluates the Monte Carlo simulation at each point.

Comment: That's what he said.  But his code is distributing them randomly throughout the rectangle.  And in general, a Monte Carlo simulation involves finding some point in the rectangle, asking your question of that point, and then repeating with another point.  Spreading them uniformly would not be the way to go.  But OP definitely could have been clearer as to what he wanted.